# I used AutoRec on my LG Gpad 7.0 LTE and it wiped my storage

Tags: data-recovery, formatting

When I used [AutoRec](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2715496), a recovery tool on my Android tablet, it instantly shut down and whenever I connect it to a PC, it shows up as a removable storage device and there are only 2 remaining folders titled `/Images` and `/verinfo` with 8.26 MB on the storage in total.

What happened? Any assistance? I think I completely formatted my tablet and I hope that isn't the case.

Comment: I don't know "this recovery tool" (link?) – but what [usb-connection-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-connection-mode/info) you are using? To me that looks like "camera mode" (PTP), in which you can only see/access the camera pictures of your device.

Comment: From the app description, I guess you just wiped out the partition and completely formatted your tablet...

Answer (score -1):

Change camera mode PTP to media mode MTP type connection...then you will be able to see the storages of internal & external as  removable device ..
Go to setting > usb connection 
There you will find the option to change connection mode

Comment: -1, [LG Gpad 7.0 LTE](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g_pad_7_0_lte-6554.php) by default comes with Android 4.4.2, and Kitkat has no support for "USB Mass Storage". Make corrections, write clearly, and I'll take my downvote back. Thanks!

Comment: In the case you have formated your device then you can only browse the content only if your device is rooted(root access) using linux commands while connecting to a linux computer system..

Comment: I'm just saying that "USB Mass Storage" isn't available for Kitkat (device running it) which you've suggested. It has nothing to do with root. The MTP part may be helpful but the poor structure of the answer has mixed it with Mass Storage. Consider correction please. At this point, your answer isn't helpful, but it can be. Thanks! and good luck with the editing.